# AngularJS - Pass Value to Component

Tags: html, angularjs, data-binding, angular-components

I am trying to pass a value from one component into another component.

**Location List**

```
<div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" heading="{{location.name}}" ng-repeat="location in $ctrl.locations">
  <p>This is from location list: {{location.id}}</p>
  <bike-list locationId="{{location.id}}"></bike-list>
</div>
```

Output:

This is from location list: 1

Location id is:

**Bike List**

*bike-list.component.js*

```
angular
.module('bikeList')
.component('bikeList', {
    templateUrl: 'bike-list/bike-list.template.html',
    controller: ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
        var self = this;
        self.bikes = $rootScope.currentBikes;

    }],
    bindings: {
        locationId: '<'
    }
});
```

*bike-list.template.html*

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Location id is : {{$ctrl.locationId}}</p>
</body>
```

Output:

Location id is:

**Question**

- How can I get the locationId to bike-list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I changed `<bike-list locationId="{{location.id}}"></bike-list>` to

```
<bike-list location-id="location.id"></bike-list>
```

Which solved my problem!

Output:

This is from location list: 1

Location id is: 1

Answer (score 1):

Instead `<bike-list locationId="{{location.id}}"></bike-list>` change it to

```
<bike-list location-id="$ctrl.location.id"></bike-list>
```

angular normalize attrs and you can read more about it in [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes)

working example can be found in [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/U1AxlM1Quthv7T49ergD?p=preview)

Comment: That causes an error.

The output is now:

This is from location list: 1

Location id is : {{$ctrl.locationId}}